# Ubuntu 11.10 could not start just after installation

Tags: 11.10, installation, boot

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on quite old machine (AMD Sempron 2200+).

After rebooting I see only followed information:

```
* Checking battery state...     [OK]
fsck z pakietu util-linux 2.19.1
/dev/sda1: clean, 141591/2403744 files, 940774/9606656 blocks
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
* Starting AppArmor profiles    [OK]
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
Checking for running unattended-upgrade:
* Starting bluetooth
* PulseAudio configured for per-user sessions
saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
```

and nothing more.

Ctr+Alt+Delete cause normal restarting (stoping processes and so on).

What is going on? How could I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried booting from the live CD or USB?

Comment: you could try to boot into recovery mode by selecting it in the boot menu and then try to start a root shell

Answer (score 0):

Please wait some times at the time of booting.
May be you are selected *recovery option from grub boot menu*

Comment: After waiting several minutes (about 15 or so) the same information was displayed but not in the same order ("* Checking battery state" was displayed as last). I do not rebooting or switching off computer. Still waiting.